# Two active URLs for prestashop?

Tags: prestashop, domain-name

How can I set up 2 different active URLs (domains) for prestashop so that the site can be accessed from both of them?
Parking the second domain doesn't work because prestashop will redirect it to the main domain.

Comment: Please checkout prestashop multi-store feature. this will allow you use as many urls as you want with the same products.

Comment: I want to use it on version 1.4.8